# Can I read dict using "user input"?

Tags: python, dictionary

It works for my game:

```py
import random

ships = {
    "transporter": {
        "type": "transporter", "price": 5000
    },
    "scout": {
        "type": "fighter", "price": 8000
    },
    "interceptor": {
        "type": "fighter", "price": 100003
    }
}

player_ship = random.choice(list(ships))
print(player_ship)
```

Is it possible to read key: value using input?
E.g.

```
player_ship = input("Choose a ship:")
```

and when the user enters `"1"` he will choose `"transporter"`?

Thanks for your suggestions. I feel a bit enlightened! :)
I also found a very good source:https://www.pythonpool.com/dictionary-to-list-python/
Peace to everyone!

Comment: Does 2 map to scout, and 3 map to interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible:

```py
userInput = int(input("Choose a ship: "))
print(ships[list(ships)[userInput-1]])
```

##### Example output #1

```
Choose a ship: 1
{'type': 'transporter', 'price': 5000}
```

##### Example output #2

```
Choose a ship: 2
{'type': 'fighter', 'price': 8000}
```

Note that, you have to define the `ships` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
user_ship = int(input("Choose a ship:"))
list_of_ships = list(ships)
print(list_of_ships[user_ship - 1])
```

Comment: Who reviews your code?

Comment: I think the answer can illustrate my point, but yeah I can clean it.

Comment: "Code-only" answers are discouraged as they only solve the problem rather than enlighten. c.f. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Answer (score 0):

With current structure you have to do what @Amirhossein suggested. However, this entails to keep another list for keys.

If you're only going to use `ships` for this purpose, you could write `ships` this way:

```py
ships = [{"name": "transporter", "type": "transporter", "price": 5000},
         {"name": "scout", "type": "fighter", "price": 8000},
         {"name": "interceptor", "type": "fighter", "price": 100003}]
```

then:

```py
userInput = int(input("Choose a ship: "))
print(ships[userInput - 1]['name'])
```

Now you can access the list container easily by index.